# Need to post into an array with PHP and jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, input

I have an array in PHP and I have an input field, I was wondering how to get my value in the input field into the array?

```
array(
"message"=>$_POST['test'],
"others"=>"blah"
)

<input type="text" id="putIntoArray" >
<a href="#" onclick="jqueryPOST(this.value);">Post</a>

function jqueryPOST(value){
  var message = $("#putIntoArray").val();
  //I dont know how to put this value into "message" array?
}
```

So with the Post link, it should take the input value into the array "message", but not sure how to? would this also be the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post('url_here',{ parameter:value, parameter:value, parameter:value});
```

[like in your case - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d6CHx/):

```
<input type="text" id="putIntoArray" >
<a href="#" id="post">Post</a>​

//attaching click handler
$('#post').on('click',function(){
    jqueryPOST();
});

function jqueryPOST() {

    var message = $("#putIntoArray").val();

    //the something you didn't know :)

    $.post('/echo/json/', {
        test: message            //<<<HERE's test!
    }, function() {

        //what you want to do after?
        alert('posted!');

    });

}​
```

Comment: what about the $_POST['test']?

Comment: I have an array already, I'm not trying to create an array. I'm trying to push the input value into the existing array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use post as @joseph said or you can use

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "your url for posing data",
            data:"test="+value,
        });
```

Comment: You could even use `$.post()`, then you do not have to specify the type.

Comment: if you notice my answer, I said that you can use @joseph said way
and joseph suggested $.post way

Comment: I did notice that, I just didn't read all of the answer of @Joseph.